# JavaFX всплывает пустое окно при смене одного окна на другое

Tags: java, javafx

Прошу помочь разобраться в непонятном поведении JavaFX приложения при переходе между окнами.

Имеется три класса: Main.java, NewGameWindowController.java и NewMainMenuController.java

И два fxml файла: newGameWindow.fxml и newMainMenu.fxml в каждом окне есть всего лишь одна кнопка

Структура приложения: при запуске отображается newMainMenuController.fxml, при нажатии на кнопку это окно закрывается и открывается newGameWindow.fxml. На окне NewGameWindow есть кнопка, которая делает ровно обратное: закрывает окно NewGameWindow и открывает окно newMainMenu.

Проблема: запустил приложение, нажимаю на кнопку для перехода из newMainMenu в newGameWindow, всё отрабатывает как надо, затем нажимаю на кнопку для перехода из newGameWindow в newMainMenu и с 70% вероятностью вместо нужного окна с кнопкой появляется пустое окно. В остальных 30% случаев открывается newMainMenu, затем нажимаю на кнопку для перехода из newMainMenu в newGameWindow и уже 100% получаю пустое окно.

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/newMainMenu.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("JavaFX application");
    stage.setWidth(640);
    stage.setHeight(480);

    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Application stops");
    super.stop();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

newMainMenu.fxml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controllers.NewMainMenuController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="openGameMenuBtn" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="143.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="openGameMenu" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

NewMainMenuController.java :

```
package sample.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewMainMenuController {

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button openGameMenuBtn;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    openGameMenuBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
        openGameMenuBtn.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        Parent root1 = null;
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        try {
            root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/newGameWindow.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(root1 == null){
            System.out.println("oh fuck1");
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX application");
        stage.setWidth(640);
        stage.setHeight(480);
        stage.showAndWait();
    });
}
}
```

newGameWindow.fxml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controllers.NewGameWindowController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="goBackToMainBtn" layoutX="236.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="GoBackToMain" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

NewGameWindowController.java :

```
package sample.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewGameWindowController {

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private Button goBackToMainBtn;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    goBackToMainBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
        goBackToMainBtn.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        Parent root1 = null;
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        try {
            root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/newMainMenu.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(root1 == null){
            System.out.println("oh fuck1");
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX application");
        stage.setWidth(640);
        stage.setHeight(480);
        stage.showAndWait();
    });
}
}
```

Updated: Обнаружил ещё один странный момент. Когда появляется пустое окно, можно кликнуть в то место, где должна была быть кнопка, и она отработает, окно сменится, но снова на пустое, где так же можно "нащупать" кнопку.

Comment: openGameMenuBtn.getScene().getWindow().hide(); Проблема здесь скорее всего.

Comment: Очень плохая идея постоянно подгружать контроллеры, да ещё и в методе initialize. Лучше создать видимость между ними, и использовать hide show напрямую.